# How do I resolve dependencies when linting single javascript files with grunt?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jshint, gruntjs

I want to separate my application logic into multiple Javascript files for sanity and developer friendliness, stored in the /src folder. These files should be linted and concatenated into /dist/app.js during the build process. I am using grunt for my build process, as it already comes with handy lint and concat tasks.

```
    +
    |- grunt.js
    |- readme
    |-vendors
       |-backbone.js
    |- src
       |- core.js
       |- user.js
    |- dist
       |-app.js
```

I am running into an annoying problem. I use backbone.js for application structure, and most of my source files start by defining models by extending **Backbone.Model**. When linting these files, JSHint complains that Backbone is not defined, and rightly so - backbone resides outside in its own directory. Including all necessary scripts in the right order is something I assume is done in the html. Each individual source file should only know about itself.

I know that I can suppress these **undefined** warnings by setting lint's **undef** flag in grunt.js to **false** but I want to keep it set to **true** in order to be warned about other undefined variables in my application, as it is a common pointer to typos. Is there a clean way to tell grunt (or lint) what files to include prior to linting them? Am I doing something wrong with my build process, or with my application architecture? Or is this simply something I have to live with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `jshint` options allow you to specify a list of globals that come from other libraries you are using, in your grunt.js file:

```
    jshint: {
      options: {
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        immed: false,
        latedef: true,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        undef: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true,
        browser: true
      },

      globals: {
        jQuery: true,
        Backbone: true,
        _: true
      }
    },
```

note the `globals` setting at the bottom. This allows JSHint to ignore these variables, but still run your `undef: true` setting (as shown above).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I was pretty sure there had to be an easy way to do this, but grunt's documentation wasn't very clear and I had no prior experience with JSHint. Thanks again!

Comment: Adding something like `core.js` to the example `globals` in the answer would help clarity.  I was coming from a Web Storm perspective wondering how I would add items defined in my own lib before I realized I could add them to the file.  Might also want to mention that you can add the options to just a single file with the `/*global key:value, .. */` syntax

Comment: I continued to get "'foo' is not defined" until I moved the globals object inside the options object.

Comment: The value bound to each global determines whether assigning a value to it is acceptable. Given that, all three globals above should have `false` values.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (that doesn't rely on grunt) is to add a jshint comment into your js files:

```
/* global Backbone, jQuery, _ */
```

Comment: And if your script needs to assign a value to a global, append `:true` (no spaces) after it. For example `/* global Backbone, jQuery:true, _ */`